# как прописать код для беседы (vk_api bot python) что бы бот автоматически удалил нежелаемые сообщения # ('abcd') допустим

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

[924] Can't delete this message for everybody

выдает такую ошибку что делать?
спасибо

```
import vk_api
import random
import time




vk=vk_api.VkApi(token='**********')
while True:
    try:
        messages = vk.method("messages.getConversations", {"offset": 0, "count": 20, "filter": "unanswered"})

        if messages["count"] >= 1:

            id = messages["items"][0]['last_message']["from_id"]
            user=vk.method('users.get',{"user_ids":id})
            body = messages["items"][0]['last_message']['text']
            last_message_id=messages["items"][0]["last_message"]['id']
            anun_user=user[0]['first_name']
            group_id=messages["items"][0]["conversation"]["peer"]['id']

            if body.lower()== 'abcd':

                vk.method('messages.delete', {'message_ids': last_message_id,
                                              'spam':0,
                                              'group_id': group_id,
                                              'delete_for_all': 1})
                vk.method("messages.send",
                          {"peer_id": id, "message": "no deleted", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})


            else:
                vk.method("messages.send",
                          {"peer_id": id, "message": "Не понял тебя!", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
    except Exception as E:
        print(E)

        time.sleep(1.5)
```

Comment: Посмотрите документацию и приведите то, что у Вас не получилось.

Comment: Изучив api - этот метод ждёт от тебя список идентификаторов сообщений, разделённых через запятую. 
соответственно, определение "нежелательности" сообщения следует сделать ранее. 
Приведи метод определения нежелательности, или свой код - на выходе которого будет массив с сообщениями, которые надо будет удалить.
Документация по этому методу: https://vk.com/dev/messages.delete